# GIT Pull from Remote Origin Ignoring SSH Keys - Asks For Password

Tags: linux, git, authentication, ssh, remote-access

The basic problem is that every time I execute a git pull, I am asked for a password.

#### Servers

I have a 2-server setup. Server1 hosts the git remote origin. Both server1 and server2 pull from that server1 origin into their web-accessible folders.

#### Users

The same 2 users are on both servers: an admin user and a file user. The admin user has the ability to behave as root, and the file user owns the files. Both users belong to the same group. The file user and the group own the web-accessible files, and, on server1, the remote origin files.

#### SSH

The server1admin, server2admin, and the server2file users have been set up to ssh using public keys as server1file user, and if I try to ssh directly from the command line, everything works as expected.

#### GIT

On server1, the git origin is /git_repos/repo.git

On server2, the git origin is ssh://server1file@server1/git_repos/repo.git

### The Problem, Rephrased

When I am logged into server2 as server2admin and execute git pull, I'm asked for the server1file user's password, and I don't know why.

Curiously enough, if I change the origin on server2 to ssh://server1admin@server1/git_repos/repo.git, I am asked for the server1admin user's password.

Any ideas about what I should look at to figure out why a password is necessary?

Comment: first step would be to check `.ssh/authorized_keys` on server1. On server2, doing `ssh server1file@server1` works without having to login?

Comment: @RandolphCarter Yes, logged in as both users on server2, `ssh server1file@server1` succeeded. I ended up adding some more authorized_keys entries allowing server1 users to ssh as server2file, and everything started working. Wish I knew why, but I'm glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

try running the command `ssh-add` on server 2

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure why, adding server1file and server1admin users to server2file user's authorized_keys file fixed the issue.